# can you use rel=opener with window.open()?

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I know you can use "noopener" with window.open, which explicitly tells your browser to forbid the child window from accessing the parent window.  This should have the affect of using rel="noopener" in a hyperlink.

However, Chrome 88 is soon (2021?) going to make "noopener" the default.

So is there a way to do the opposite, and explicitly set it to "opener"?  So that the child window DOES have access to the parent window?  I'm hoping to fix my link before it breaks with the newest Chrome.

I assume it'd be the code below?  I'm not sure how I'd test this before the next version of Chrome releases.  But I also don't want to wait to make this change until after my link breaks with the next release.

```
window.open(url,'_blank','toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,opener')
```

or

```
window.open(url,'_blank','toolbar=1,menubar=1,location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1', 'opener')
```

Comment: I didn't find references to this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/12/chrome-88-deps-rems). Where did you read that this would soon be the default?

Comment: Oh, see it [here](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/12/chrome-88-digital-goods-lighting.html)

Comment: I imagine we'll just have to wait for the official Chrome blog post to tell us how to enable it when it comes out

Comment: @NL3294 is there a problem in my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTML specification is clear about this, you can check it [here.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#apis-for-creating-and-navigating-browsing-contexts-by-name)

I will share the first segment of the `window.open` steps:

> The window open steps, given a string url, a string target, and a
> string features, are as follows:
>
> 1. If the event loop's termination nesting level is nonzero, return
>    null.
> 2. Let source browsing context be the entry global object's browsing
>    context.
> 3. If target is the empty string, then set target to "_blank".
> 4. Let tokenizedFeatures be the result of tokenizing features.
> 5. **Let noopener and noreferrer be false.**
> 6. If tokenizedFeatures["noopener"] exists, then:
>
>    1. Set noopener to the result of parsing tokenizedFeatures["noopener"]
>       as a boolean feature.
>    2. Remove tokenizedFeatures["noopener"].
> 7. If tokenizedFeatures["noreferrer"] exists, then:
>
>    1. Set noreferrer to the result of parsing
>       tokenizedFeatures["noreferrer"] as a boolean feature.
>    2. Remove tokenizedFeatures["noreferrer"].
> 8. If noreferrer is true, then set noopener to true.

You can see also in [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=898942) bug tracker, which is tied to the commit that added that, that the edit is only concerned with anchors. I quote

> Anchor target=_blank implies rel=noopener

The reason this edit is only done in anchors is because using `window.open` to trigger this attack would fall into XSS since it requires injecting JavaScript code.

The security issue this bug is concerned with, is that a user can put bad code in a page that you refer to but don't have access to. You can see it doesn't require Same Origin [here.](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) Another possible attack vector is when there is user-generated content on your website but this is unlikely since you are likely to escape the user input for XSS.

Final note, this edit is already available for you to test in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Thanks, I just marked this as the answer.

But can you clarify why anchors needed this fix but not window.open?  If I put an anchor to blah.com using target=_blank without using noopener, then they can tabnap.  If I put a window.open to that same site with target=_blank, without noopener, how is that any safer?

Comment: @NL3294 You as a developer can control the `window.open` behavior so if f you didn't pass `noopener` then you want `opener` to be filled. This is not what happens with url. You can link to any other site with an anchor. But you only use `window.open` when you want to control the new tab with features. Imagine you shared something on Facebook and any one who clicks that link get tab napped because facebook didn't implement no opener. `window.open` is purely used to control the child so a link to part is expected by default.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to test this to confirm it works 100% but according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for window.open, the `windowFeatures` parameter can be passed as comma-separated key-value pairs where you have `key=value` so you can do `noopener=false`. If you do this in the current chrome version then the `window.opener` of the new window is actually the previous window as if you hadn't set anything so I would assume that would work in the new chrome version when it comes out.